# Datatables server side processing hits database when clicking Print View option

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, server-side

Datatables server side processing hits database when clicking Print View option using Table Tools.

```js
if (gridcount != null && parseInt(gridcount) > 0) {
            _displayCount = parseInt(gridcount);
        }
 loaddatatable();  



function loaddatatable()
    {
_fromdate = $('#FromDateSelect').val();    
        _todate = $('#ToDateSelect').val();    
        $('#ddBankAccountYears').val($('#HBankAccountYear').val());   
        _Year = $('#ddBankAccountYears').val();    
        oTable = $('#List').dataTable({    
            "bStateSave": true,    
            "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {    
                $('#displayCount').val(oData.iLength);    
                $('#SortType').val(oData.aaSorting[0][1]);    
                $('#SortColumn').val(oData.aaSorting[0][0]);
            },
            "sDom": 'l<"floatR pL5"T><"floatR"f>rtip',
            "bDestroy": true,
            "aaSorting": [[_SortColumn, _sortType]],
            "iDisplayLength": _displayCount,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/ControllerName/AjaxHandler?id=" + _AccountId + "&id2=" + _Year + "&fromdate=" + encodeURIComponent(_fromdate) + "&todate=" + encodeURIComponent(_todate),
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": []
  });
      }
```

here is the sample of the code we use and exactly issue is when we click on the Print view option of Datatable using table tools. the Ajax Method is getting hitted and get the values. Actually it shouldn't hit the Method it should show or grab datatable alone and display.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue using TableTools extension *2.2.4* 
The way I handled to avoid hitting again the controller is by using **`"bShowAll": false`** [option](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options).

Also I initialize TableTools by [using](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation) `$.fn.dataTable.TableTools`.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//server side processing
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/app/api/class/getData",
        "type": "POST",

        // additional params for the method (optiona)
        data: {
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "date"},
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "email"},
    ],
    "language": {
        "processing": "<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\"></i>"
    }
});

// append data tools
appendDataTools();

// initialize the TableTools and then append to DOM
function appendDataTools() {
    var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {

        // it uses a Flash SWF file to provide the ability to
        // copy text to the system clipboard and save files locally.
        "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

        // select which buttons to display and export only the visible columns
        // now the exporting only the selection is broken
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bSelectedOnly": true
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bSelectedOnly": true
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "print",
                "mColumns": "visible",
                "bSelectedOnly": true,
                "bShowAll": false
            }
        ]
    });
    var dataTools = $("#dataTableTools");
    dataTools.append(tt.fnContainer());
}
```

});

Note: As of 2015-09-04 TableTools extension is retired. Looks like that is being replaced by [Buttons Extension](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/). Although I could not see a *print* button, hope to see it soon tough :)